# How to apply a material to an object of an 8 sided conical shaped roof

Tags: edit-mode

I have asked a similar question before, received the reply and was able to apply materials to different faces but for some unknown reason to me it does not work for this object (roof of lighthouse which has been worked into an 8 sided cone shape).
I select the roof in object mode change to edit mode and select one face, select my material from the material list and every face is 'mapped' with the material. When I then go to uv editing there is no 'shape' displayed to work on (scale the material).

[image]

New 'clean' Blender file with no materials

[image]

Comment: To avoid [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). perhaps it would be better to state your _goal_ clearly, here.Personally, I'm not leaving a read of this post with a clear idea of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have multiple materials on the object if you want some parts to have one materials, other parts another. If you have a single material, there is nothing else that can be assigned to all other faces that you don't have selected. To see UVs of the object you need to be in edit mode, and have the desired geometry selected in 3d viewport as well(select all with <kbd>a</kbd> to see the whole UV map)

Comment: Thanks. I must be overlooking what you mention as I still cannot do it.      Firstly I want to apply the same material to each face but obviously as each face is in a different direction I need to apply that same material to each face and then uv edit to get the direction and scale correct BUT when (in edit mode)  I select ONE face, open UV editing I do NOT see the 'shape' of the face I have selected.

Comment: If I select only one face then all I see in the UV editing map is a single line. If I select all faces I see 8 single lines in the uv editing map. I want to see triangular shapes in the uv editing map.

Comment: @JohnArnold I guess that's because you didn't UV unwrap your object. The mesh primitives (or at least some of them) like cube, sphere come with a "ready-to-use" UV map, but depending on how you have created the roof it does not have a correctly usable UV map or no UV map at all.

Comment: Yes I did.  Firstly I add my texture image material in Object Mode (the entire roof is 'painted'). I then go to edit mode, press Ctrl-E and choose mark seam, press U twice and then click on UV editing and the material displays in new window on left of screen as usual HOWEVER the roof/faces are not 'mapped'. I have used this method many times and it has never failed me until now.  I then go back to 'layout', go to edit mode again, select just one face and attempt to assign the material. Still no luck. That works when I add a material to one of the 8 sided cylinder meshes ok but not the roof

Comment: The UVs ar not unwrapped correctly. You might want to look into [UV Unwrapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/unwrapping/index.html). Basically you can just mark edges as seems(ctrl+e -> Mark Seam) and unwrap (U->Unwrap). Then you can ajust the UV map. What you now see in the UV editor is correct when you select a triangle face - those faces are mapped to flat lines and that is not very useful in this situation so they probably need to be unwrapped some other way.

Comment: Thanks. I found a youtube video where the author states that cones are notoriously difficult to map. I then decided to replace the roof of my lighthouse with a CONE mesh (I had created it with a CYLINDER mesh, select all edges at the top and then scaled 'IN'. Well 'blow me down' my new roof made using a mesh CONE is easily mapped.

Comment: I don't know what they are talking about. Cones are no different than any other kind of tidy geometry. Pretty much any geometry is quite easy to unwrap in Blender once you mark seams in right places(except messy stuff like non-manifold geometry, concave n-gons and all the other evil you should not have in your models anyway) . I wouldn't worry about it. I think it's just that you are not used to this process. once you practice a bit more and get used to the ways stuff works it should become easy.

Comment: @JohnArnold You said you press Ctrl+E and choose _Mark Seam_, but that's not what you did on the blend file which can be downloaded in your question? Because there are no seams, those edges would be marked in red. Or did you do it without any edge selected? It only makes seams from the selected edges.

Comment: I must have given you an incorrect Blender file as I removed any materials I may have used and then started again as I described above. Sorry.  I now also wonder if the problem with mapping is due to the fact that the roof was made with a SINGLE 8 sided cylinder with a height (Z axis) of 0.2 meters then I extruded the top face on the Z axis 2 meters on the Z axis and then selected all the edges on the top face and scaled 'IN' so the single mesh object consists of 18+ faces and I wanted to map the material to just 8 of them. I am now using TWO separate meshes (1 cylinder and 1 cone) which works

Comment: Gordon. If the edges are supposed to be marked in red as you state then there must be another issue as when I mark seams the edges are BLACK. As this could now be regarded with a different title I have created a new question. Please note though that I have uploaded a new blender file which is 'clean' ie no materials etc.

Comment: IN a late reply to Martynas' method I now see that when I go to edit mode and press the A key BEFORE doing anything else and the the black edges then turn to yellow and then I can mark the seams.               I can't remember what I was trying and in what order but obviously incorrect.                              My only excuse was that I was over tired having tried to solve this myself over a few HOURS before posting and and not having my mind correctly on the task from frustration.